# AWS API Gateway missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have Enabled Cors in api gateway for my routes which are integrated with lambda function. But there is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header preset in response of 'OPTIONS' call by browser. Any help is appreciated.
I have even added manual headers in lambda function, but no luck.

[image]

[image]

Here is my cross origin resource sharing configuration.
[image]

Here is my prod stage API Gateway configuration
[image]

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to hit the API?

Comment: @Chris Pollard, I ended up creating new function with one of the serverless repository. Thanks for the reply.